# Why are there not primality tests based on comparing the candidate $n$ with values of some $k \in [0,n]?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, primality-test

I am learning basic number theory and as far as I could read, basically all the primality tests (or proven primality theorems) that are able to decide if a given $n$ is prime (or a special pseudoprime) are based on the comparison of $n$ versus a usually big quantity $\in [n+1,..)$

I am not including prime sieves in the concept of primality test, because they imply normally more comparisons than a primality test (e.g. the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes))

For instance I am considering as primality tests (not in order of importance, just as I recall them):

- [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) (requires powers, e.g. $2^n$)
- [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) (requires $n!$)
- Fibonacci-Lucas primality tests ($F_n$ grows up very quickly)
- Catalan primality tests ($C_n$ grows up very quickly)
- Pascal's triangle binomial coefficients modularity (requires binomial coefficients so factorials grow up very quickly)
- Any other [probabilistic tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Probabilistic_tests).
- etc.

All those primality theorems and properties, when applied to their tests require a set of several numbers bigger than the candidate $n$ to be tested.

"Under $n$" there are prime number sieves, but if I am not wrong there are not primality test based on some comparison with a value $k \in [0,n]$ in the way that the above mentioned theorems are applied, and all the proven theorems seem to imply that any primality property is obtained by comparing values "over $n$" and not "under $n$", but is that point a necessary condition?

I understand that one possible answer is just that "they were not found yet, if they exist" but in other hand: is there a prove that any primality property in the fashion of the above theorems is possible if and only if the comparison is done with a number bigger than the candidate $n$?

So the question I would like to share is:

> Why are not there primality tests (or primality properties, or theorems of primality) based on comparisons of $n$ and some value $k \in [0,n]$? Is there a proven theoretical impossibility behind it?

Thank you!

(If there are online references to this topic, they are also very welcomed, and as usual I will remove the question is is not very clear, please just let me know)

Comment: The tests associated with Fermat's Theorem do not involve numbers enormously bigger than $n$, for we can use the binary method of modular exponentiation, reducing mod $n$ at each step.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you for the explanation! (I understand they still are "over $n$").

Comment: It seems like you are grasping at notions of complexity theory in the hope of comparing various primality tests. See for example the [Wikipedia exposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test#Time_complexity) on the (time) complexity of the Lucas-Lehmer primaility test. You need to consider both space and time complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick answer is that all algorithms involve numbers modulo $n$, and in particular you never go beyond $n$. The algorithms give you a recipe – an algorithm – of computing some numbers modulo $n$ and comparing them. Sometimes this recipe can be summarized as an expression which, if not performed modulo $n$, will be larger than $n$. Such a succinct representation is misleading, since all arithmetic is done modulo $n$, and even intermediate results never get larger than $n^2$ (since everything reduces to addition and multiplication).

Comment: thank you for your answer, that is right, everything is based in modulo n, what I wonder is why there are not primality tests able to obtain the same results using a number $k$ related with the candidate $n$ but $k \lt n$, the test could be also modulo $k$ but defining the primality of n. It seems that such kind of primality property is not possible, is that right?